# How to draw on top of an Image in CodeName One?

Tags: codenameone

I have been successful in drawing arbitrary paths on the whole screen by modifying the definition of SignaturePanel class according to need. Next, I want to want to able to draw on any picture selected by the user. Basically, the picture should remain in the background and I should be able to manipulate it. I tried the mutable image but I don't quite get how to implement it. Some sort of code to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have coded this far:

Main Class:-

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;


import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.Painter;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.io.MultipartRequest;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.URLImage;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Rectangle;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.painter.PainterChain;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class MainClass {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    SignaturePanel sp;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
        hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Button browseGallery = new Button("Browse");

        Image test = Image.createImage(1280, 800, 0xffff00);
        hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,test);

        hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, browseGallery);
//        browseGallery.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
//
//          @Override
//          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
//              Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
//
//                  @Override
//                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                      
//                  }
//              }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
//          }
//        }
        browseGallery.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {

                            //Image mutable = Image.createImage(1280, 800, 0x00ff00);
                            //Image image = URLImage.createImage((String)evt.getSource());
                            //hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER,mutable);
                            //image.modifyAlpha((byte) 10);

                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
            }
        });
//        hi.setGlassPane(new Painter() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              System.out.println("glasspane");
//          }
//      });

        sp = new SignaturePanel();
       // hi.getLayeredPane();
       // hi.add(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(new LayeredLayout(), sp);
        System.out.println("before adding");
        hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp);
        System.out.println("after adding");
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

SignaturePanel :-

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Font;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Stroke;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Dimension;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Rectangle;

class SignaturePanel extends Component {

    private final GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    private final Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
    private final Rectangle signatureRect = new Rectangle();
    private final Font xFont;
    private Image value;

    SignaturePanel() {
        stroke.setLineWidth(Math.max(1, Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1, true)/2));
        getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffff00);
        getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(10);
        xFont = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_LARGE);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to try to make this component as sensitive as possible to 
     * drag events.  If we don't do this, it requires a longer drag before the "drag" 
     * events will kick in.
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    protected int getDragRegionStatus(int x, int y) {
        return Component.DRAG_REGION_LIKELY_DRAG_XY;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param g 
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(0x666666);
        calcSignatureRect(signatureRect);
        g.drawRect(signatureRect.getX(), signatureRect.getY(), signatureRect.getWidth(), signatureRect.getHeight());
        g.drawString("X", signatureRect.getX() + Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1, true), signatureRect.getY() + signatureRect.getHeight() / 2);
        paintSignature(g);
    }

    /**
     * Paints just the signature portion of the panel.  This is is reuised to
     * also create the image of the signature.
     * @param g 
     */
    private void paintSignature(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(0x0);
        boolean oldAA = g.isAntiAliased();
        g.setAntiAliased(true);
        g.drawShape(path, stroke);
        g.setAntiAliased(oldAA);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates a rectangle (in parent component space) used for the drawn "rectangle" inside
     * which the user should draw their signature.  It tries to create a 16x9 rectangle that
     * fits inside the component with a bit of padding (3mm on each edge).
     * @param r Output variable.
     */
    private void calcSignatureRect(Rectangle r) {
        int w = getWidth() - Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(6, true);
        int h = (int)(w * 9.0 / 16.0);
        if (h > getHeight()) {
            h = getHeight() - Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(6, false);
            w = (int)(h * 16.0 / 9.0);
        }
        r.setX(getX() + (getWidth() - w) / 2);
        r.setY(getY() + (getHeight() - h)/2);
        r.setWidth(w);
        r.setHeight(h);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        Display d = Display.getInstance();
        return new Dimension(d.convertToPixels(100, true), d.convertToPixels(60, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
        path.moveTo(x(x), y(y));

        value = null;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
        path.lineTo(x(x), y(y));
        value = null;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
        value = null;
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Converts an x coordinate from screen space, to parent component space.
     * @param x
     * @return 
     */
    private int x(int x) {
        return x - getParent().getAbsoluteX();
    }

    /**
     * Converts a y coordinate from screen space to parent component space.
     * @param y
     * @return 
     */
    private int y(int y) {
        return y - getParent().getAbsoluteY();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the currently drawn signature as an image.  This only includes the 
     * areas inside the {@link #signatureRect}
     * @return 
     */
    private Image getImage() {
        calcSignatureRect(signatureRect);

        Image img = Image.createImage(signatureRect.getWidth(), signatureRect.getHeight(), 0xffffff);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.translate(-signatureRect.getX(), -signatureRect.getY());
        paintSignature(g);
        return img;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the signature as a blank path.
     */
    private void clear() {
        path.reset();
    }
}
```

Please ignore the commented out code

Comment: FYI we already have a signature component in Codename One and you can also inspect its code here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/SignatureComponent.java

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from there and modified the definition according to my need. This was much easier @ShaiAlmog thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image as a background of your component as in sp.getAllStyles.setBgImage(), then override paint(Graphics g) on the component as you are now. You should then have the image with your drawn shapes laid on top.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you @James

Comment: Any idea how to make an eraser work so that the background before the image gets exposed on the path the eraser is used?